# JQuery slideshow no animation if selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fade

I have a JQuery slideshow on this webpage http://www.2eenheid.de/cloud/.

When clicked on a menu item like 'Cloud', the background fades to its image. Even after hovering in and hovering out on a different menu item, it fades back to this 'Cloud' image.

Now it does this also when hovering in and out on the 'Cloud' item too. It fades out and fades back in with the same image. It's supposed to not do anything if the image is the same. It looks kind of messy with that many fades. Any clue on how to do this with my code?

**JQUERY**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var imgsrc = '';
            imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');

            $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
                var newImg = $(this).attr('src');
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });

            }, function () {
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': imgsrc
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but where in the code would i put this? I tried a couple of places but doesnt work..

Comment: I changed everything as you suggested. Yet nothing has changed, it still works the same. When I am on the "Cloud" page and I hover on the "Cloud" menu item, it still fades again. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
        var newImg = '';

        $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').mouseover(function () {
            newImg = $(this).attr('src');
            $('.pikachoose')
            .fadeOut('fast')
            .css({'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'})
            .fadeTo('slow', 1);
       });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't right, it doesn't go back to the right image now!

Comment: Thanks I got it working like its supposed to by changing the last 'newImg' back to 'imgsrc' but now it works as before. Nothing has changed? When I am on the "Cloud" page and I hover on the "Cloud" menu item, it still fades. :(

Comment: try `mouseover` , no need for callbacks i suppose, the picture url has to be the `src` of the currenty hovered link right?